# How to prevent Opera from scrolling page with overflow:hidden?

Tags: css, opera

Here's really annoying bug(?) in Opera, best illustrated with example: http://nanotux.com/plugins/fullscreenr/index.html . While the given demo works correctly in other browsers, in Opera it is possible to scroll content using mouse wheel or cursor keys.
Is there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are two ways to do this:

**CSS**

```
position: fixed
```

In other words...

```
<body style="position: fixed;">
```

**JS**

```
window.onscroll = function(event){window.location='#test';};

<body id="test">
```

This option is very herky-jerky, so hopefully the position: fixed will get it done. I tested on Opera 11.

Comment: Thanks, position:fixed worked. By the way, scrolling issue only occurs on lower screen heights (like netbooks).

Comment: No problem. BTW, I've got a 1680x1050 display and I was seeing the issue you described. Apparently, Opera may consider it a feature.

Comment: No, we don't consider it a feature. It's a very annoying (and, sadly, old) bug with various painful side effects on important sites like Google Maps and Google Docs. I'm so looking forward to it finally being killed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Hallvors. It's been awhile since I've been on my.opera.com.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an Opera feature. There are some badly written pages that contain text that is cropped by overflow:hidden and this greatly helps accessing them. Opera has always been on the side of the user - the user can do anything with the page and this is just one of the consequences.

If you don't need the space that is being cropped by overflow:hidden, why not shorten it yourself?